# Build Query button missing in phpMyadmin Designer view

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp, wampserver

after adjusting my config.inc.php file, creating the pma user, and uploading the SQL file from the examples folder, my designer tab is present now in my phpMyadmin (running WAMP Apache/2.2.22 (Win32) PHP/5.3.13).
But, the most important button, **the buld query button, is missing**!? I hope you can help me fix this so i can output the queries!

thanks
ben

Comment: When you say the "build query button" is missing, you mean you don't see the SQL tab?  Or the `Visual Query Builder`?  Sounds like a browser issue.  Try a different browser.

Comment: the  button that, as i understand, normally is right after the "import / export coordinates for PDF" button when in designer view. so its the last button in the row of designer view functiond - save position, create table, create relation, etc. Without it i can link tables in designer but cant output the code to use. At least thats the obvious use of designer..

Comment: Same here. There are also no checkboxes next to columns in the visual designer, though there ARE in the standard view.

Comment: Perhaps a screenshot would help show what is missing in your case.